# How do I get a block and its content commited to a Git repo?

Tags: 7, blocks, version-control

Let's say I have created a block with some Full HTML (Facebook Feed) text inside. How can I commit the block and its text content into my Git repository, so my co-workers can pull it?

Comment: how is this question related to Drupal?

Comment: Because the block is in Drupal?! Or what do you try to suggest?

Comment: Drupal blocks store its html/text into database, why you need git for?

Comment: As I mentioned, I want my co-workers to be able to pull it through Git. As easy as that.

Comment: @Aboodred1 This is definitely a Drupal issue (a pretty common one actually). There's an entire [Drupal 8 initiative](http://groups.drupal.org/build-systems-change-management/cmi) dedicated to solving the general problem of config management. This is about as relevant as it gets :)

Comment: @koivo  Do you have a local repo or are you using GitHub?

Comment: Storage engine is irrelevant - "how to export * from Drupal?" for me is definitely a Drupal question.

Comment: Why not [override the block](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) with the relevant [block.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!block!block.tpl.php/7) template file. In that way you can easily manage the block contents using Git. The drawback is of course that the block can't be managed in the Drupal admin UI, but it can also be a plus if users with edit block permission are not supposed to edit it. So it all depends.

Comment: I worked on a site that used this approach. Bad, bad idea. Many hours wasted on looking "where this string came from?". On small sites, under hundred blocks / thousand nodes it might even work. On large ones it's a suicide.

Comment: I merely proposed an alternative working answer to the question. Never claimed it was the best solution. You had already provided the better solution.

Comment: And I just wanted to warn people about problems with this approach I experienced.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turn it into a [Feature](http://drupal.org/project/features). Bad thing is, it does not work on built-in custom blocks, so you need to use [Boxes](http://drupal.org/project/boxes) to get it work.

That way, you can export block as a module, and modules are text files, so GIT accepts them with it's full support.

Then, there is [Features to Git](http://drupal.org/project/features_git) module. It claims:

> Features to Git allows trusted users to write features directly to disk, commit
>   them to git and push them to a remote. This makes it possible for site
>   builders to be able to manage features in git without having to get their hands
>   dirty on the command line.

Comment: +1 for using Boxes-- this works, although from my experience it's a bit of a pain (e.g., if you need translations, you also have to add i18n boxes module).

Comment: Everything have it's ups and downs. Built-in blocks needs Block languages module too! I don't claim boxes are easy. I'm not going to claim my answer is best. But from my experience it is an answer (except the Features to Git, it's from Google, not experience).

Comment: Uhhh Thank you very much!!! That worked like a charm!!!

1. I installed and activated [Boxes](http://drupal.org/project/boxes)
2. I created a Box (Structure >> Blocks >> Add Box) and inserted my HTML text (plus set the text format to Full HTML)
3. I created a Feature with the module and the box inside (worked like a charm, box appeared immediately)
4. pushed it into the repo and that's it

My co-worker pulled it, acivated it and put everything in the right place again.

Answer (score -1):

Create a module for that block using the [Features](https://drupal.org/project/features) module and then commit that module on to the GIT repository of yours.

For more information you could read the README.txt of feature module from.